# Ubuntu 18.04.1 Freezes randomly

Tags: freeze

I use a Asus P553M processor Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N2940 @ 1.83GHz × 4, Graphics intel Bay Trail, Memory 3,7 GiB.
It freezes randomly, I've tried ubuntu gnome, ubuntu 18.04, Xubuntu....

I don't have any windows installed. I erase everything and install linux only...

I need help!!!

Thanks!

Comment: How much RAM? How much SWAP? `free -h`. If you have no SWAP, read `man mkswap;man -a swapon`.